# Difference between third party modules libraries?

Tags: python

this is an odd question to ask, it's actually my first here on stackoverflow. I'm learning about Python and it's benefits, and came across a webpage that says that **some of the benefits of Python are**:

> [**Presence of third party modules and extensive support libraries**](https://www.invensis.net/blog/it/benefits-of-python-over-other-programming-languages/)

. To my understanding (so far) these are the same thing.

Comment: Look at the descriptions of the two given in the article.

Comment: I have. I'm not a native english speaking person, maybe that's why I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: The article is differentiating between modules that tend to come with python distributions the "standard libraries" and modules you can pull in from other places - sometimes great high quality stuff, sometimes smoldering piles of garbage. They are all modules in the general sense.

Comment: Actually, they are not always just modules. They can be larger projects that include python and other things.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that having a healthy ecosystem of libraries isn't uniquely Python. It's a minimum expectation of today's popular programming language/framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the article third party modules are those imported through PyPi (or other methods) - for example the `numpy` module; extensive support libraries are part of the standard library that you do not need to download (batteries included) - for example `collections`

> 1. Presence of Third Party Modules: The Python Package Index (PyPI) contains numerous third-party modules that make Python capable of
>      interacting with most of the other languages and platforms.
> 2. Extensive Support Libraries: Python provides a large standard library which includes areas like internet protocols, string
>      operations, web services tools and operating system interfaces. Many
>      high use programming tasks have already been scripted into the
>      standard library which reduces length of code to be written
>      significantly.

Note that in your program you still need to import these modules

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
```